# HTML: <div> tag making <p> content bold without instruction

Tags: html, bold

I have been trying to make a mini website today based on a character from a video game, and I decided to implement some  tags to separate the content into different sections. I decided to place  tags on each of four 'abilities' that the character has, and suddenly text within paragraph elements within the div elements were made to be bold. I don't believe that I made them bold myself, does anyone know why this has happened?

I styled the div tags in the head element with a font-weight attribute of value 400 to remedy the problem, however I didn't think that this would be necessary.

I reckon that I have overlooked something basic here, and it would be nice to have some different eyes on my work to spot the error. Thanks to anyone who can help me, I am posting the code below.

```css
body {
  background-color: purple;
  color: peachpuff;
}

img {
  float: left;
}

p {
  color: peachpuff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div {
  color: peachpuff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="color:peachpuff;text-align:center;font-size:64px;text-decoration:underline;margin:0px;">Enigma</h1>
<p style="margin:0px;text-align:center;">Enigma is a hero from Dota 2.</p>
<h2 style="font-size:45px;margin:47px 50px 0px;text-decoration:underline;color:peachpuff;">Abilities
  <h2>

    <div>
      <h3>Malefice</h3>
      <p style="font-size:18px;margin-top:3px;">Focuses Enigma's power on a target, causing it to take damage and become repeatedly stunned for multiple instances. An instance strikes every 2 seconds.</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h3>Demonic Conversion</h3>
      <p style="font-size:18px;margin-top:3px;">Transforms a creep into three fragments of Enigma himself. These eidolons are all under Enigma's control, and repeated successful attacks cause them to multiply. When this happens, the eidolons have their health restored.</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h3>Midnight Pulse</h3>
      <p style="font-size:18px;margin-top:3px;">Steeps an area in dark resonance, damaging enemy units based on their max HP.</p>
      <p style="color:purple;margin:-1px 0px 0px 0px;">lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h3>Black Hole</h3>
      <p style="font-size:18px;margin-top:3px;">Summons a vortex that sucks in nearby enemy units. Enemies affected by Black Hole cannot move, attack, or cast spells.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: You didn't close your opening body element `<body`. You also misclosed your h2 element `Abilities<h2>`

Comment: oops my mistake, I accidentally removed the > when pasting it into stack overflow and editing it a bit to remove some images I wasn't allowed to include. Thanks for spotting, the opening tag is fine in my original file as far as I can see.
Edited the post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two coding typos which are causing the issue. First, you need to close the body with right angle bracket. Second, you need to close the `<h2>` with the forward slash.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: purple;
      color: peachpuff;
    }
    
    img {
      float: left;
    }
    
    p {
      color: peachpuff;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    div {
      color: peachpuff;
      font-size: 20px;
      /*font-weight: 400;*/
    }
    
    h3 {
      font-size: 30px;
      margin: 0px;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 style="color:peachpuff;text-align:center;font-size:64px;text-decoration:underline;margin:0px;">Enigma</h1>
  <p style="margin:0px;text-align:center;">Enigma is a hero from Dota 2.</p>
  <h2 style="font-size:45px;margin:47px 50px 0px;text-decoration:underline;color:peachpuff;">Abilities
  </h2>

  <div>
    <h3>Malefice</h3>
    <p style="font-size:18px;margin-top:3px;">Focuses Enigma's power on a target, causing it to take damage and become repeatedly stunned for multiple instances. An instance strikes every 2 seconds.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Demonic Conversion</h3>
    <p style="font-size:18px;margin-top:3px;">Transforms a creep into three fragments of Enigma himself. These eidolons are all under Enigma's control, and repeated successful attacks cause them to multiply. When this happens, the eidolons have their health restored.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Midnight Pulse</h3>
    <p style="font-size:18px;margin-top:3px;">Steeps an area in dark resonance, damaging enemy units based on their max HP.</p>
    <p style="color:purple;margin:-1px 0px 0px 0px;">lorem ipsum.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Black Hole</h3>
    <p style="font-size:18px;margin-top:3px;">Summons a vortex that sucks in nearby enemy units. Enemies affected by Black Hole cannot move, attack, or cast spells.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, yeah I think the forward slash on the closing h2 tag was the issue. Thanks very much for spotting this and pointing it out.

Comment: Glad that is able to help